# SQL - Filter Records Where year is 2

Tags: sql, filter

I am back in the sofa now (UK time)
i am doing (not trying) a appraisal system and i would like to filter all the records based on a person where the year is 2, this means they have filled forms for the year 2.

The output i need is a table with the user name and the columns which have 2 in it.

Below is what i have re re re done.

```
[SELECT DISTINCT
dbo.profiles.profile_id,
dbo.profiles.profile_fname,
dbo.lesson_observation.lo_year,
dbo.self_assess.sa_year,
dbo.staffappraisal_head_dept.sahd_year,
dbo.staffappraisal_main_meeting.samm_year,
dbo.staffappraisal_mainapprs_followup.samafu_year

FROM
dbo.profiles
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.lesson_observation ON dbo.lesson_observation.lesson_obsv_profile_id = dbo.profiles.profile_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.self_assess ON dbo.self_assess.self_assess_profile_id = dbo.profiles.profile_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.staffappraisal_head_dept ON dbo.staffappraisal_head_dept.sa_hd_profile_id = dbo.profiles.profile_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.staffappraisal_main_meeting ON dbo.staffappraisal_main_meeting.sa_mainappraisal_teacherid = dbo.profiles.profile_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.staffappraisal_mainapprs_followup ON dbo.staffappraisal_mainapprs_followup.sa_ma_fup_teachers_id = dbo.profiles.profile_id
WHERE
dbo.lesson_observation.lo_year = 2 OR
dbo.self_assess.sa_year = 2 OR
dbo.staffappraisal_head_dept.sahd_year = 2 OR
dbo.staffappraisal_main_meeting.samm_year = 2 OR
dbo.staffappraisal_mainapprs_followup.samafu_year = 2
GROUP BY
dbo.profiles.profile_id,
dbo.profiles.profile_fname,
dbo.lesson_observation.lo_year,
dbo.self_assess.sa_year,
dbo.staffappraisal_head_dept.sahd_year,
dbo.staffappraisal_main_meeting.samm_year,
dbo.staffappraisal_mainapprs_followup.samafu_year`][1]
```

Below is the picture that this outputs.

I dont want repeated records.
Thank you for every single answer that everyone send i really appreciate it.

v

---

thanks for the comments and i appreciate all of them.

i will try to explain in more details what i have.

i have a table of users which contains

> profile_id profile_fname profile_lname

each user needs to fill in an appraisal every year, so when they submit the forms below, the field year will have (1 or 2 or 3), these are the 5 tables

```
tb1 - lesson_observation
tb2 - self_assess
tb3 - staffappraisal_head_dept
tb4 - staffappraisal_main_meeting
tb5 - staffappraisal_mainapprs_followup
```

each above table have the following fields

```
tb1
tb1.field1
tb1.field2
tb1.field3.profile_id
tb1.year

tb2
tb2.field1
tb2.field2
tb2.field3.profile_id
tb2.year

tb3
tb3.field1
tb3.field2
tb3.field3.profile_id
tb3.year

tb4
tb4.field1
tb4.field2
tb4.field3.profile_id
tb4.year

tb5
tb5.field1
tb5.field2
tb5.field3.profile_id
tb5.year
```

What i would like to achieve an output like this.

```
User ID    | Fname| Lname | TB1 Header | TB2 Header | TB3 Header | TB4 Head etc
----------------------------------------------------------------------
33         | john | wayne | 2          | null       | 2          |  2
```

Where only brings the Unique records of each user of all the users that have filled in the year 2

once again i appreciate your time and patience with me.

I have tried to format this time a bit better ;-)

thanks

Comment: what columns do you need...you have a * with 7-8 tables...you cannot possibly need all of them

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: where are the infos you wanna show? In which table(s)? Cause if you need only profiles table then I would replace all the joins with "exists"

Comment: Change the first line of your query from "SELECT *" to "SELECT DISTINCT *". This should solve your issue. Now, please help me understand why do you want to do a FULL Outer JOIN. Full Outer Join will basically include all values from both tables irrespective of whether they match or not. Also, do you need all the columns? To know more about joins, please refer to: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com